# iOS tableview animated placeholder

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, placeholder, loader

Is it possible to use below library in ios when the tableview data is getting from server. Initially the row count will be zero until we get the data from server.
https://github.com/malkouz/ListPlaceholder
https://github.com/samhann/Loader.swift
Please help me if its possible using this.
I need to show FB like placeholder in tableview until I get data from server.

Comment: What have you tried by your own means to solve the issue? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I did it with separate cell before loading the data. Its working.

Comment: Initially I tried with the same cell used for showing data. But it was not working. Now I used separate cell and conditionally set the number of rows. Working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly looks like it does what you want - although I'm not sure how customisable it is? Grab the 'Example' project and have a play!

However, I'd suggest taking a different approach and just return a row count of 1 while your loading your data. Then in your `cellForRowAt:` method create a 'loading cell' if your still loading which you can style to look exactly how you want. When your data finishes loading just call `reloadData` on your tableview, this time returning the correct row count and returning your fully populated cells.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this. I have tried with their example and tried in my app. since the row count is zero didnt load the placehlder cells.